# How to recover/reset forgotten Cryptkeeper password?

Tags: encryption

I am using `Cryptkeeper` in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to encrypt my important files. Unfortunately I have forgotten my `Cryptkeeper` password. It is very important for me to recover all those files. I have frustrated searching on google. Would you please someone help me :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIR, cryptkeeper is an EncFS gui frontend, it sounds like you should've ran EncFS in a terminal, is that what happened to fix it?

Comment: This is how I fixed it: When I run `gksu cryptkeeper` it's prompt me for a password, actually that was not my cryptkeeper pass, it's root pass. That was the reason. My root pass and crypt pass are different. Finally I enter my root pass, then click on the icon from launcher, it runs.  P.S. without  `gksu cryptkeeper` it doesn't run.

Comment: I haven't run cryptkeeper for a while, but EncFS is supposed to work without root. Cryptkeeper may require it though, not sure.  Anyway, all's well that ends well. PS. now you know how important backups are, especially for encrypted data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you use `cryptkeeper`?
To protect your data from other people's eyes.

It would not have been protected if anybody could simply crack the encryption. And how should the application distinguish between an evil attacker and you?
Because you should know the encryption password. When you forget it, that's your problem. The application will be as graceful to you as to any evil attacker and that's good this way, because otherwise it woud be useless.

In my view, you have three options:

1. Forget about the data. It's gone. Poof!
2. Buy a supercomputer for millions of dollars and spend days/weeks/months/years (depending on the strength of your old password) with letting it try to brute-force decrypt your data. Also don't forget about the electricity bill. Supercomputers are no power savers.
3. Sit down and try to remember the password. Maybe visit a hypnotist?

Comment: :( Well said. I have no way to go with option 3.

Comment: Or brute force it.  Easy if you can remember at least parts of the password.

Comment: @SiddiquiNoor why are you not able to follow option 3?

Comment: In case we're not talking about your very own encrypted data, it would be illegal and morally incorrect to help you anyway.

Comment: @Zacharee1 yes trying. Making a list of tried password and it's getting bigger :(

Comment: @ByteCommander I understood.

Comment: It was not my password fault. When I run  `gksu cryptkeeper` it asks the password for root, I entered cryptkeeper, that was my actual fault. Finally I run `gksu cryptkeeper` enter my root pass then click on the cryptkeeper icon from launcher, it runs. When I click on encrypted folder and put the cryptkeeper pass, it works. Voila! thanks you all guys.